# how to check if an item is clicked or not in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to develop a whack-a-mole web game with javascript, but i'm new to this and i would really appreciate some help. I wanna check if the mole is clicked or not, cause if it's not, I want the player to lose a life and also I want to make the start button only work once.
This is the code so far:

```js
const holes = document.querySelectorAll('.hole');
const scoreBoard = document.querySelector('.score');
const moles = document.querySelectorAll('.mole');

let lastHole;
let timeUp = false;
let score = 0;



function randomTime(min, max) {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

function randomHole(holes) {
    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * holes.length);
    const hole = holes[index];

  
    if (hole === lastHole) {
        return randomHole(holes);
    }
    lastHole = hole;
    return hole;
}

function peep() {
    const time = randomTime(500, 1000); 
    const hole = randomHole(holes); 
    hole.classList.add('up'); 
    setTimeout(() => {
        hole.classList.remove('up'); 
        if (!timeUp) {
            peep();
        }
    }, time);
}

function startGame() {
    
    scoreBoard.textContent = 0;
    timeUp = false;
    score = 0;
    
    peep();
    setTimeout(() => timeUp = true, 90000) 
}

function wack(e) {
    if (!e.isTrusted) return;
    score = score + 100;
    this.parentNode.classList.remove('up'); 
    scoreBoard.textContent = score;
 
}


moles.forEach(mole => mole.addEventListener('click', wack))









<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sheet2.css">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <button onClick="startGame()";>Start</button>
    <span class="score">0</span>
    
    <div class="game">
        <div class="hole hole1">
            <div class="mole"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="hole hole2">
            <div class="mole"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="hole hole3">
            <div class="mole"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="hole hole4">
            <div class="mole"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="hole hole5">
            <div class="mole"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="hole hole6">
            <div class="mole"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="hole hole7">
            <div class="mole"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="hole hole8">
            <div class="mole"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="hole hole9">
            <div class="mole"></div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortuantely this is likely to be considered too broad. Try to boil your issue down to a specific problem and post only the code relating to that problem, not all your code.

Comment: I am impressed with your code, for someone who's "new to this", I've certainly seen *much worse*. I hope this doesn't go to your head, hehe :) As for your problem -- you need to ask yourself "what constitutes a hole with a mole peeking out of it?" -- that determines whether what the player clicks on should bring them score or not. You only seem to check whether the click is "authentic" (coming from a human, through `isTrusted` property) and just assign more score if it is. I am actually surprised you can't solve this, having solved so much already. Hint: check if the hole has the `up` class.

Comment: I agree with @Mitya though -- this looks more like a forum post. Try to distill your question into the minimal example (CSS can, for example, be omitted completely) that demonstrates what you have trouble with, and mention in detail what you want and what you have tried and how you tried to approach it. At the core of your question, there isn't actually any question -- more of a "I am stuck, help". As such, you already *seem* to answer your own question -- you know how to check "if an item is clicked or not", do you not? You mean an item other than the one you listen on? Sorry for being stern.

Answer (score 0):

Add `id` to start button so you can disable it in `startGame()`
What is `if (!e.isTrusted) return;`?
You have event when clicked!
Check if `up` - if yes, continue (add score, etc.), if no, end game...