# How to check if an element is clicked

Tags: javascript

```html
<div class="game">

        <div class="hole hole1">
            <div class="mole"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="hole hole2">
            <div class="mole"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="hole hole3">
            <div class="mole"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="hole hole4">
            <div class="mole"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="hole hole5">
            <div class="mole"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="hole hole6">
            <div class="mole"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="hole hole7">
            <div class="mole"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="hole hole8">
            <div class="mole"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="hole hole9">
            <div class="mole"></div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

```css
.game {
    width: 300px;
    height: 600px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 0 auto;
    
}



.hole {
    flex: 1 0 33.33%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

    .hole:after {
        display: block;
        background: url('gaura1.png') bottom center no-repeat;
        background-size: 100%;
        content: '';
        width: 100%;
        height:100%;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 2;
        
    }

.mole {
    background: url('flowAlb.png') bottom center no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    top:100%;
    transition: all 0.4s;
    
    
 
}

.hole.up .mole {
    top: -20px;
    z-index:3;

}
```

I'm trying to learn web development with CSS, HTML and JAVASCRIPT(i'm new to all of them) and I'm working on some whack-a-mole game code that was free to work with. I understood what the code does, but I'm not sure how to work with. I have an event listener on click for each mole, but I wanna do something if the mole isn't clicked and I don't know how to check that. I tried different methods, using boolean variables or trying to check if the click was outside the element, but none of them worked. I'm pretty sure I didn't used them right, so I would really appreciate some help or information. I'll leave here the JS code. Thanks so much!

```js
const holes = document.querySelectorAll('.hole');
const scoreBoard = document.querySelector('.score');
const moles = document.querySelectorAll('.mole');
const mySound=document.getElementById("sound");
const joc=document.getElementsByClassName("game");

let lastHole;
let timeUp = false;
let score = 0;


function randomTime(min, max) {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

function randomHole(holes) {
    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * holes.length);
    const hole = holes[index];

  
    if (hole === lastHole) {
        return randomHole(holes);
    }
    lastHole = hole;
    return hole;
}

function peep() {
    const time = randomTime(500, 1000); 
    const hole = randomHole(holes); 
    hole.classList.add('up'); 
    setTimeout(() => {
        hole.classList.remove('up'); 
        if (!timeUp) {
            peep();
        }
    }, time);
}

function startGame() {
    
    scoreBoard.textContent = 0;
    timeUp = false;
    score = 0;
    
    peep();
    setTimeout(() => timeUp = true, 90000) 
    
}



function wack(e) {
   if (!e.isTrusted) return;
   score = score + 100;
   this.parentNode.classList.remove('up');
   scoreBoard.textContent = score;
  
   

}



moles.forEach(mole => mole.addEventListener('click', wack));
```

Comment: Add the event listener to it where action is click

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to check if an item is clicked or not in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62593831/how-to-check-if-an-item-is-clicked-or-not-in-javascript)

Comment: change your this with `e.target` or `e.currentTarget`

Comment: Add a click handler to the body and check for `var target = (event.srcElement || event.target)`. You can even remove your other click handlers by doing that. Would make an example, yet your code is not runnable/complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a click event to the `documentElement` and check its target. Consequently you could also remove your other click handlers while doing this and check for the class `mole`.

```js
;document.documentElement.onclick = function(event){
  //REM: Target element of the click
  var tTarget = event.srcElement || event.target;
  
  //REM: Check which element was targted.
  if(tTarget.id === 'sample'){
    alert('You clicked on #sample')
  }
  else{
    alert('You clicked on "' + tTarget.tagName + '"')
  }
};
```

```css
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%
}

body{
  background: yellow
}

div{
  background: red
}

.sample{
  background: lime;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class = 'sample'>
  <div id = 'sample'>click me or not</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would be a better idea to check the explict element, as checking everywhere on the document would expect the canvas to be 100% of the browser and also doesnt seem bug safe as it wouldnt be isolated code.

Comment: @PatricNox: That assumes there being explicit elements for everything. The 100% part I do not comprehend (sounds simply wrong) and the isolation can be done same as everywhere, if wanted/required.

Comment: @Lain thanks! i'm gonna try it right now. i was wondering if i could check it after score? if it increases, the mole was hitted, if not, u missed